# Junit Spring Portlet with MockMvc post request

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, mockmvc

Need to test the redirect in action response using mockmvc in Junit

**Controller.java**

```
@ActionMapping(param="submit")
public void handleSubmit(ActionRequest req, ActionResponse res) {
  ...
  res.sendRedirect("https://google.co.in"):
}
```

**ControllerTest.java**

```
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;

public ControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockmvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
      controller = new Controller();
      mockmvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void redirectTest() throws Exception {
       mockMvc.perform(post("/action").param("submit", "value")).
                    andExpect(redirectedUrl("https://google.co.in"));
    }
}
```

The problem is, the controller method is not called on post perform from Junit.

The url in browser on click of submit looks as `action/rparam=action=submit.wsp`

Comment: I don't think that Spring's WebMvc testing framework is setup for `@ActionMapping`.

Comment: How do you set tell the framework that the controller listens to `action/*`?

Comment: @StefanBirkner the url will have parameter "submit". The annotation @ActionMapping(param ="submit") will handle it.

Comment: But you have to define the base url `/action` somewhere.